# Salvar chave com vários valores em arquivo Properties

Tags: java, propriedade

Tenho um arquivo `.properties` onde carrego o nome dos testes que serão excluídos da minha aplicação. Esse arquivo precisa ter o mesmo nome das "variáveis" já que todas significam a mesma coisa (testes excluídos), o problema é que meu código está apenas reconhecendo o último teste (o NATONE no caso).

dados.properties:

```
prop.teste.excl = CQT-SUST
prop.teste.excl = NATONE
```

código:

```
public static Properties getProp() throws IOException 
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("src/resources/dados.properties");
    props.load(file);
    return props;

}

public ArrayList<String> testeInterno() throws IOException 
{
    String property;
    ArrayList<String> testeInt = new ArrayList<String>();

    Properties prop = getProp();

        for ( int i = 0; i < prop.size(); i++)
        {
            property = "prop.teste.excl"; 
            testeInt.add(i, prop.getProperty(property));

            System.out.println(testeInt.get(i));
        }

    return testeInt;
}
```

Pensei em colocar ";" no final de cada linha do meu arquivo porém não sei fazer o código que reconheça o ";" como final de linha e também não sei se daria certo.

Comment: Você consegue adicionar a pergunta qual a mensagem de erro que ocorre?

Comment: não mostra um erro, porém ele não consegue pegar o primeiro teste (CQT-SUST) só retorna o (NATONE)

Comment: Alterando a sequencia, colocando o (CQT-SUST) por ultimo ele retorna dai?

Comment: sim, ele estava pegando só o ultimo. Mas já consegui resolver com a resposta do Articuno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode inseri-los na mesma chave de propriedade separando por virgula, e depois você trata o retorno como `String`, separando os valores com o método `split`, passando a virgula como separador:

Exemplo:

```
prop.teste.excl = CQT-SUST,NATONE
```

E na hora de tratar:

```
String[] array = prop.getProperty("prop.teste.excl").split(",");
```

Dessa forma, você tera um array com os valores da chave `"prop.teste.excl"`, que foram separados por virgula.

Comment: ótimo! Obrigada!